# Is it possible to make a hyperlink to a certin line of a pdf or doc?

Tags: pdf, documents

I'm looking for an open-source tool that can make a hyperlink to a certain place within a doc or pdf rather than the file itself. So after click the link , I can directly see the content I'm interested in the file .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about *a line*, but you can, according to [this](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/317/317300.html), link via hyperlink to a PDF page. Would that help a bit ?